How can I format a partition in a mapper device?
I created a mapper device with dmsetup and created a partition table with parted:
$ fdisk -l /dev/mapper/vdisk
Disk /dev/mapper/vdisk: 511.57 GiB, 549295737344 bytes, 1072843237 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: OMITTED

Device                       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/mapper/vdisk-part1   2048     204799     202752    99M EFI System
/dev/mapper/vdisk-part2 204800 1072841188 1072636389 511.5G Microsoft basic data

Now how do I manipulate the partitions, say format the first partition to FAT? /dev/mapper/vdisk-part1 or /dev/mapper/vdisk1 don't seem to exist.
PS: I do remember /dev/mapper/vdisk1 or something similar appeared after creating the partition table with parted, but disappeared after a reboot.

May you share the dmsetup command you used ? May you share the result of ls -lhiar /dev/mapper/ ? thanks

Just a general observation, but unless you are using the mapper device as part of a multipath setup or as storage for a VM disk image, it’s almost always preferable to partition the underlying devices because essentially the entire storage stack on Linux expects things to be done that way, so it will largely ‘just work’ without any need for special handling on your part.

Kernel by default doesn't look for partitions on DM devices so you need to tell it to do that with a tool like partprobe (from parted project) or kpartx (from multipath project; kpartx creates DM linear devices for the partitions).
$ sudo partprobe /dev/mapper/vdisk

or
$ sudo kpartx -a /dev/mapper/vdisk

$ lsblk /dev/mapper/vdisk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
vdisk 253:2    0   2G  0 dm   
$ sudo kpartx -a /dev/mapper/vdisk
$ lsblk /dev/mapper/vdisk
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
vdisk    253:2    0   2G  0 dm   
└─vdisk1 253:3    0   2G  0 part


You can create offset loop devices that refer to individual partitions and operate on them. For example, to map the first partition:
losetup --offset 1024576 --sizelimit 103809024 /dev/loop0 /dev/mapper/vdisk

Now, /dev/loop0 is your partition, it's where you do mkfs and whatever. After use, do losetup -d /dev/loop0 to detach.
The numbers are calculated as follows: offset = start * 512, sizelimit = (end + 1 - start) * 512 = sectors * 512, where 512 is a sector size. (Not all versions of fdisk show partition size in sectors, some show in blocks, typically of 1K; to resolve ambiguity I use the fields that are definitely always know.)
